# how to bulk edit node in drupal?

Tags: drupal, cck

I add 1 CCK field and want edit this for any content(500 nodes). how to edit this nodes together?

Tnx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are familiar with developing modules, you can create a custom module to define an action and then use the the [Views Bulk Operations module](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to run that action on a particular set of nodes.

If you need or want to perform the edits manually (say, if each node needed a unique value), the [editablefields](http://drupal.org/project/editablefields) module might be better.

Comment: i installed editablefields but for example when upload file to edit,node dont not edit!!